# KPSS test & ADF test - range to choose for lags

Tags: stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

Suppose I want to check if a series is stationary with the KPPS test;
the literature suggests to take as lags $\sqrt n$ where $n$ is the number of observations. Do you agree with the literature?
Which range would you then choose to test if it is stationary? 
$\sqrt n +-1$ or I do not know...$\sqrt n +-10\% \sqrt n$?

While for ADF tests I have seen that sometimes it is used $12(n^{1/4})$ do you agree with this?